# Response.json() is not a function error is getting thrown, but it wasn't before and nothing has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

I'm creating a react site and trying to call an API I made. Initially  the fetch request was going through fine, Then, I added a call to a `PUT` mapping which worked fine, but when I went back to retest the `GET` request, it started giving the .json is not a function error. I tried removing the new API call to revert to how it was when it worked, but it didn't help. Additionally, I tried adding `method:GET` to it just in case.

```
const sakilaResponse = await (`http://localhost:8080/home/filmsInCategory/${sakilaInput}`, {method: "GET"});
      sakilaText = await sakilaResponse.json();
      console.log(sakilaText);
      sakilaOutput.innerHTML = sakilaText;
```

Comment: I think you wanted to use `fetch` instead of nothing?

Comment: I don't know how that disappeared. I feel silly now, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use in fetch or axios, for example:

fetch:

```
const sakilaResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/home/filmsInCategory/${sakilaInput}`, {method: "GET"});
sakilaText = await sakilaResponse.json();
console.log(sakilaText);
sakilaOutput.innerHTML = sakilaText;
```

axios:

```
import axios from "axios";

const sakilaResponse = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
sakilaText = await sakilaResponse.json();
console.log(sakilaText);
sakilaOutput.innerHTML = sakilaText;
```